# How to determine if the java script function still running?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have concern regarding of javascript function, The question is there any indicator to determine if the javascript function still on going or still running? because I have problem on inserting hundred of items inserting in the database. I want to condition if the javascript function still on going the insertion will stay until the condition met the else if the javascript function is not running or done, it will automatically redirect to the other page.

In my onclick of my jquery I insert the javascript function.

```
    $('#add_to_cart').on('click', function() {

  orders = [];
  menu = undefined;

  $('.tbody_noun_chaining_order').children('tr').each(function() {
    $row = $(this);
    if ($row.hasClass('condimentParent')) {
      if (menu) {
        orders.push(menu);
      }
      menu = {
        'total': $row.find('.total').text(),
        'name': $row.find('.parent_item').text(),
        'customer_id': customer_id,
        'condiments': {
          'Item': [],
          'Qty': [],
          'Total': []
        }
      };

    } else if ($row.hasClass('editCondiments')) {

      menu.condiments.Item.push($row.find('.child_item').text());
      menu.condiments.Qty.push($row.find('.condiments_order_quantity').text());
      menu.condiments.Total.push($row.find('.total').text());
    }
  });

  if (menu) {
    orders.push(menu);
  }





  storeOrder(orders)




});
```

My Javascript Function

```
    function storeOrder(data) {

  var customer_id = $('#hidden_customer_id').val();
  var place_customer = $('#place_customer').text();

  $id = "";
  $total_amount  = $('.total_amount').text();
  $append_customer_noun_order_price = $('.append_customer_noun_order_price').text();
  $tax_rate = $('.rate_computation').text();
  $delivery_rate = $('.del_rate').text();

  var sessionTransactionNumber_insert = localStorage.getItem('sessionTransactionNumber');

    $.ajax({
      url:'/insert_customer_order_properties',
      type:'POST',
      data:{
        'hidden_customer_id': customer_id,
        'hidden_customer_address': place_customer,
        'sessionTransactionNumber': sessionTransactionNumber_insert
      },
      success:function(data) {

        $id = data[0].id;

        $.ajax({
          url:'/insert_customer_payment_details',
          type:'POST',  
          data:{
            'hidden_customer_id': customer_id,
            'total_amount': $total_amount,
            'customer_sub_total': $append_customer_noun_order_price,
            'tax_rate': $tax_rate,
            'id_last_inserted': $id
          },
          success:function(data) {

             localStorage.removeItem('sessionTransactionNumber');

          }
        })
      }
    })

  for (var num in orders) {

    $.ajax('/insert_wish_list_menu_order', {
      type: 'POST',
      context: orders[num].condiments,
      data: {
        'append_customer_noun_order_price': orders[num].total,
        'append_customer_noun_order': orders[num].name,
        'customer_id': customer_id
      },
      success: function(orderNumber) {

        $order_number = orderNumber[0].id;

        $.ajax({
          url:'/insert_customer_order_details_properties',
          type:'POST',
          data:{
            'order_number': $order_number,
            'data_attribute_wish_order_id': $id,
          },
          success:function(data) {

              console.log(data);

          }
        })

        if (orderNumber !== undefined) {

          $.ajax('/insert_wish_list_menu_belong_condiments', {
            context: orderNumber,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
              'ParentId': orderNumber,
              'Item': this.Item,
              'Qty': this.Qty,
              'Total': this.Total
            },
            success: function(result) {

              console.log(result);

            },

          })

        }
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Where are you inserting in the database?

Comment: Guess you're using AJAX to store data, than in `success` method/callback add your redirection.

Comment: @trincot I use the ajax of jquery. to insert the data. however i have multiple ajax where I inserted in different tables. in just one click

Comment: @skobaljic yes.. I can't add redirection because I have multiple ajax where I insert different value . in just one click

Comment: Than just use jQuery's [when deferreds](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/). Take a look at [3rd example here](https://blog.kevinchisholm.com/javascript/jquery/using-jquery-deferred-to-manage-multiple-ajax-calls/), or at bottom of [this page](https://css-tricks.com/multiple-simultaneous-ajax-requests-one-callback-jquery/).

Comment: Although it is all possible with building on the promise (deferred) nature of what jQuery returns, it will be *much* easier (and reliable) if you do all those actions in one go on the server side. Just concentrate everything in one Ajax call,  passing all data necessary to do the job, and let the server application do all the rest.

Comment: @skobaljic I add variable every ajax function then I do this function end of all  ajax  $.when(a,b,c,e).done(function(a,b,c,e){
      location.reload();
  });

Comment: In general, I would agree to mr @trincot and would try to organize better your code. If you ask why, than I would answer: because you would have no such issues as you have now, or at least much less. Please try and reorganize it. (Maybe try to gather all the data, than send it once)

Comment: I was rewriting your code to make it chain everything, but there are several issues with your code: wrong variable scope, name, ...etc, which all the more make it a tedious thing. I will not post an answer as I firmly believe this is *not* the way to do it. Lots of this logic should run at the server side.

Comment: thank you so much guys for the suggestion.